# What is the significance of mod?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I always see posts about modular arithmetic, and "equivalence", "congruence", etc, and I don't understand what part of mathematics this falls under, and what use it could be in the real word?

How can something like 'remainder' have such a big impact on mathematics?

Comment: Are you asking what the definition of congruence is? I'm sure you can find plenty of basic introductions through google.

Comment: This falls under the category of number theory and is _extremely_ useful both in mathematics and in practical applications. I suggest you read about RSA encryption, which is used to secure credit card transactions, emails, data transmission, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: I know what it means, I just don't understand how its applied in the real world

Comment: I can prove that [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number) ends in $...04575627262464195387$?

Comment: Number theory uses mod as a notation. We can use mod to point out important rules for divisability. As said above, modern encryption is entirely reliant on modulo arithmetic. Plus, modular groups are very important in group theory.

Comment: All part of the mysterious usefulness of interesting mathematics.

Comment: "I know what it means, I just don't understand how its applied in the real world"  Use your imagination.  Any system where output or significant measurement is cyclic or periodic will use it.  In particular trig functions, time measurement, encryption, etc.

Comment: "How can something like 'remainder' have such a big impact on mathematics? " because for anything which is periodic rather than cumulative, the remainder is the *entirity* of the result.  Imagine you are as to do a complicated calculation involving angular manipulation.  The important thing is the final position and orientation. That's determined by the remainder.  You actual number of times you spun to the nearest rotation is not important.

Comment: @Joffan The mysterious usefulness of mathematics: I recently discovered that the matrix of x^2-y^2 is used in quantum physics and in the study of the hydrogen atom. - Somehow all mathematics is relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can read about the [Diffie-Hellman](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman) algorithm. It is used to protect information in cryptography, and this is often used by banks and companies.

Other use you can do is to solve some equations that are not easy to attack in the integers to determine if have solutions or not. Inclusive in the finite field theory is useful. One example is the proof of the [Fermat's last theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A05) in the case of $n=5$.

Obviously there are a lot of utilities, but maybe with this is enough.

**EDIT:** @kccu posted too the RSA algorithm, that is one very important (and right now more known) as the Diffie Hellman algorithm.